# R script - least squares solution to the following

Tags: r, least-squares, nls, lm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding where two linear fits intersect in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114703/finding-where-two-linear-fits-intersect-in-r)

Given some points on a graph (usually only about 6 or 7 points), I need to find a best fit solution where the solution consists of the following:

1. Two linear lines
2. The lines must intersect
3. The intersection point (the x point) must lie between two values I specify (such as xLow and xHigh)

How would I do this using nls (or something better?)?

If there are multiple best fits, then any of them are fine. Basically, the two lines form a V.

Comment: What happens when there are multiple solutions, i.e. multiple lines?  And how is fit measured?  Via the standard method of MSE of residuals for y_hat?

Comment: yes, just the standard way that nls works.

Comment: Two lines that cross forming an X?  Or two lines that meet forming a V?

Comment: -1 This was already asked and answered in the comments of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114703/finding-where-two-linear-fits-intersect-in-r/7115758#7115758

Comment: It looks like in that question, the points were defined as being from two different groups, but here they're in one group.  CodeGuy, will you clarify?

Comment: Basically, it's one set of x values and y values (just a simple 2D plot). I want to find a bilinear solution where the two linear lines intersect at a specific point between two values I specify

Comment: I think people are missing the point, though it wasn't clear at first.  The OP is asking for a piecewise linear function with one "knot" (in the spline sense), i.e. just 2 pieces, and the knot's location is within some specified range.

Comment: I'm not aware of any R package that allows for linear b-splines with box constraints for the location of the knot.  Might be a fun little thing to program.  Of course, it could be done through easier methods.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you first do a fit of y on x and then x on y the lines will cross within the data at their joint means and they **are** both least squares fits, albeit to different data situations.