# Dealing with 0 error in nls - R script

Tags: r, nls, nonlinear-functions

Is there any way to allow my nls to have 0 residual error when it makes a non linear fit? I have cases in my data where the fit made should have 0 error, but nls always fails and spits out an error.

Can anyone show me:

1. How do I test if this is the error being spit out by nls?
2. How to allow for 0 error cases? (Perfect fits)

This is my nls call:

```
fit <- nls(y ~ ifelse(g, m1 * (x - x0) + y0, m2 * (x - x0) + y0),
            start = c(m1 = -1, m2 = 1, y0 = 0, x0 = split),
            algorithm = "port",
            lower = c(m1 = -Inf, m2 = -Inf, y0 = -Inf, x0 = split),
            upper = c(m1 = Inf, m2 = Inf, y0 = Inf, x0 = (split+1)),
            data=data.frame(x,y))
```

Comment: Grrr.  Please refer to previous questions when asking new ones (and consider modifying the old questions appropriately if they are very similar), and please don't change your account to look like someone else.  I'm going to stop answering your questions now, @CodeGuy/StanLe ...  I won't downvote the question, because taken on its own merits it's a reasonable question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127940/r-script-nls-not-working/7128102#7128102) in a previous answer, `?nls` *explicitly states* that you should not use `nls` for 0 error data. To directly quote the help file for the function you are using:

> **Do not use nls on artificial "zero-residual" data.**
>
> The nls function uses a relative-offset convergence criterion that
>   compares the numerical imprecision at the current parameter estimates
>   to the residual sum-of-squares. This performs well on data of the form
>
> y = f(x, θ) + eps
>
> (with var(eps) > 0). It fails to indicate convergence on data of the
>   form
>
> y = f(x, θ)
>
> because the criterion amounts to comparing two components of the
>   round-off error. If you wish to test nls on artificial data please add
>   a noise component, as shown in the example below.

A potentially dangerous option would be to use `warnOnly = TRUE` to force `nls` to return prior to convergence with a warning only (no error):

```
x <- -(1:100)/10
y <- 100 + 10 * exp(x / 2)
nlmod <- nls(y ~  Const + A * exp(B * x),control = nls.control(warnOnly = TRUE))
```

The above example was also taken nearly directly from `?nls`.