# R: Find intersection of two vectors

Tags: r, intersection, line-intersection

I have two vectors. I need to find the intersection between these two, and do a nice plot of it.

So, here is a very simple data frame example:

```
df <- data.frame( id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                 p <-c(5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,20,18,16,14,12,10,8,6,4,2 ),
                 q <-c(3,5,7,13,19,31,37,53,61,67,6,18,20,24,40,46,66,70,76,78))
colnames(df) <- c("id","price","quantity")

supply <- df[df$id == 1,]
demand <- df[df$id == 2,]

plot( x = supply$quantity,  y = supply$price, type = "l", ylab = "price", xlab = "quantity")
lines(x = demand$quantity , y = demand$price, type = "l")
grid()
```

Now, I can plot them and find the intersection manually, but can you make R calculate the intersection between these two lines?

The data can take huge jumps, and the lines can go from very step to nearly horizontal.

Comment: If they are lines!  I suspect you need to learn a little math before going further. Please look up some material on doing a linear fit (aka linear regression) and then go to any geometry book to get the formula for the intersection of two (nonparallel) lines.

Comment: The data is at best piece-wise linear, so you can't really do a linear approximation, it won't give the right result.

Comment: In that case, you need to come up with a definition of "intersect."  Do you want the intersection of spline fits, for example?  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? (quoting the Data Munger Guru) Finding an intersection if your source data are crappy won't help you.

Comment: @Carl : It seems to me that OP is trying to find out the equilibrium quantity and equilibrium price: quantity/price at which quantity demanded-quantity supplied. This is not programming question to me. Voting for close

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about economics

Comment: Yes it is about economics, but its an programming problem im faced with in R. How can that be off-topic ?

Comment: If it's piece-wise linear you could calculate an intersection for each combination of lines by the method described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114703/finding-where-two-linear-fits-intersect-in-r?rq=1 and stop when the intersection is located between 2 points of one of the lines used to calculate the intersection.

Comment: Have you tried `crossing.psp` in the `spatstat` package? "Finds any crossing points between two line segment patterns".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful creating your data frame.  You want `=`, not `<-`.  Also, make id a factor, for clarity.

```
df <- data.frame( 
  id       = factor(rep(c("supply", "demand"), each = 10)),
  price    = c(5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,20,18,16,14,12,10,8,6,4,2 ),
  quantity = c(3,5,7,13,19,31,37,53,61,67,6,18,20,24,40,46,66,70,76,78)
)
```

First we define common, frequent points to evaluate the quantity at.

```
quantity_points <- with(
  df,
  seq(min(quantity), max(quantity), length.out = 500)
)
```

Now split the dataset into supply/demand parts.

```
by_id <- split(df[, c("price", "quantity")], df$id)
```

Then we use `approx` to calculate the price at each of these quantities, for supply and demand separately.

```
interpolated_price <- lapply(
  by_id,
  function(x)
  {
    with(
      x,
      approx(
        quantity,
        price, 
        xout = quantity_points
      )
    )$y       
  }
)
```

Finally, the crossing point is where the absolute value of the supply price minus the demand price is minimised.

```
index_of_equality <- with(interpolated_price, which.min(abs(supply - demand)))
quantity_points[index_of_equality]
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick follow up, why `=` instead of `<-` ?

Comment: `<-` creates vectors `id`, `p`, `q` as well as `df`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1741820/134830